# ExceptionFilterAttribute force to use only the first one

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I'm using the ExceptionFilterAttribute, like this:

```
    public class HttpExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            var httpEx =  context.Exception as HttpException;

            if (httpEx != null)
            {
                var message = new HttpResponseMessage((HttpStatusCode) httpEx.GetHttpCode());
                context.Response = message;
                context.Exception = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

So, I need to go through this filter, but if it enters the 'if' condition,
I'd like it to do not enter any more filters, that's why I did the last line:

```
context.Exception = null;
```

But it's not working. How can I do that?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Basically on exception you might want to redirect the user directly to some generic error page.

Comment: Try context.Response.End()

Comment: There is no method .End() in context.Response

Answer (score 0):

Using `FilterAttribute` and `IExceptionFilter` and implementing the `OnException` with the `ExceptionContext` parameter would avoid any other filters if an exception is raised.

```
        public class MyErrorHandlerAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
        {
            public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
            {
                if (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
                {

                    //Write more exception processing code if required

                    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                    filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error" };
                }
            }
        }
```

Tested this with `OnResultExecuted`. Didn't fire when an exception got handled by the aforementioned implementaion.